# How do I resolve “Circular dependency detected” warning in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a warning about circular dependency between component and service. This is my modal component.

```
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService { }

  close() {
    this.modalService.close();
  }

}
```

This is the service:

```
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class ModalService {

 dialogComponentRef: ComponentRef<ModalComponent>;


  constructor(  private appRef: ApplicationRef,
            private cfResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
            private injector: Injector) { }



  open(title, content) {
   const contentComponentFactory = this.cfResolver.resolveComponentFactory(content);
   const modalComponentFactory = this.cfResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);

   const contentComponent = contentComponentFactory.create(this.injector);
   const modalComponent = modalComponentFactory.create(this.injector, [[contentComponent.location.nativeElement]]);

   if (title) {
     modalComponent.instance.title = title;
   }

   modalComponent.instance.active = true;

   this.dialogComponentRef = modalComponent;

   document.body.appendChild(modalComponent.location.nativeElement);

   this.appRef.attachView(contentComponent.hostView);
   this.appRef.attachView(modalComponent.hostView);
 }


 close() {
   this.appRef.detachView(this.dialogComponentRef.hostView);
 } 
}
```

I need to import ModalComponent in the service because I must use it as a parameter in resolveComponentFactory. In this service I create an open function that will be usable on other components for opening the modal;

I also create a close function in the service that I need to invoke inside the modal component when I will click on some button like "close"; and this is the reason that I need ModalService inside my ModalComponent.

I can't find a solution. How can I fix this warning?